# passing multiple hidden form fields into a single UPDATE mysql query

Tags: php, mysql

To make the code more efficient how can I write the code to UPDATE a mysql column with a single line? Is it possible?

example of the current code.

```
if (isset($_POST['editsongname'])) {
$id = $_POST['songid'];
    $newtitle = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['songname']);
    $doSongNameEdit = "UPDATE `$database_main`.`lyrics` SET `lyrics`.`title` = '$newtitle' WHERE `lyrics`.`id` = '$id' LIMIT 1" or die(mysql_error());

    $retval = mysql_query( $doSongNameEdit, $main );
    if(! $retval )
    {
        die('Could not update data: ' . mysql_error());
    }
    header("Location: song.php");
    //echo "<b>Updated Successfully</b> - <a href=\"song.php\">Return to edit lyrics page</a>\n ";
    }
```

(Form code)

```
> <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" name="<?php echo
> $sid; ?>"  method="POST"> <input type="hidden" name="songid"
> value="<?php echo $sid; ?>">
```

(example of a sid)
228106
Which directly connects the edit to the correct location in the database

So how would the Hidden form field pass dynamic information to this code so I can only streamline the code or is it even possible?

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained and the [deprecation process](http://j.mp/Rj2iVR) has begun on it. See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that using the GET method. Which means that every variable of the form shown in the address bar. You need to change the form to use the POST method

```
<form name="name" action="url.php" method="POST" target="_blank">
...
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the form method that you're using ($_GET or $_POST).

```
<input type="hidden" name="songid" value="<?php echo $sid; ?>"> 

$id = $_GET['songid']; 
-- OR --
$id = $_POST['songid']; 


$doTextEdit = "UPDATE texts 
               SET texts.text = '$newtext' 
               WHERE 
               texts.id = '$id'";
```

You don't need a `LIMIT` in your DB query either.